# Marionette: Use index to add class to ItemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I currently have a composite view, and I would like for each ItemView to render based on its index.

For example, I want to add a class to an every third `ItemView`.

The solution I'm leaning towards is altering `appendHtml()` to add a class to the view every third time. I've put the code for this below.

Is there any advantage to using `getItemView()`? A disadvantage I see is that it doesn't have direct access to the index.

**Templates**

```
<script id="list-item" type="text/html">
  <%= name %>
</script>

<script id="list-layout" type="text/html">
    <div class='collection'>
        <h3><%= name %></h3>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
var ListItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: '#list-item',
  tagName: 'li'
});

var ListComposite = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  itemView: ListItemView,
  itemViewContainer: "ul",

  template: '#list-layout',

  appendHtml: function(cv, iv, index){
    if ((index + 1) % 3 == 0) iv.$el.addClass('rowend');

    var $container = this.getItemViewContainer(cv);
    $container.append(iv.el);
  }
});
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533172/different-styling-on-the-third-record-in-backbone-marionette-rails

Comment: Thanks, David. The solution provided there seems much more conceptually sound.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use the `buildItemView`

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-builditemview

Now you won't have direct access to the index, but you can use underscores methods to fix that (these should all be augmented onto backbone collections, in particular this one http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf).

The main benefit you get is that you can directly influence the classes of the itemviews

```
var ListComposite = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  itemView: ListItemView,
  itemViewContainer: "ul",

  template: '#list-layout',

  buildItemView: function(item, ItemViewType, itemViewOptions){
       var index = this.collection.indexOf(item);

       var options = _.extend({model: item}, itemViewOptions, {className:"someClassName" + index});

       var view = new ItemViewType(options);

       return view;
  },
});
```